# OnComplete never called with toSortedList() and groupBy()

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, rx-android, rx-kotlin

I'm currently using the Android-ReactiveLocation Library ([Github](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation)). The `LastKnownLocationObservable` ([Code](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation/blob/master/android-reactive-location/src/main/java/pl/charmas/android/reactivelocation/observables/location/LastKnownLocationObservable.java)) is working as intended. I'm using a `flatMap` to fetch nearby stations from a db and (because of realm) I'm creating a model from the data. So I have a list of items and I'm creating the new Observable in `flatMap` with `Observable.from(data)`.

Then I want to sort the locations, filter them and group them.

```
.toSortedList()
.flatMap { Observable.from(it) }
.filter { it.distance <= (maxDistance.toDouble() * 1000) }
.groupBy { //Group the stations in categories
    if (it.distance <= maxDistance && it.favorite) {
        "nearbyFavorite"
    } else if (it.favorite) {
        "outOfReachFavorite"
    } else {
        "nearby"
    }
}
```

However the onComplete is never called when I subscribe to the Observable. The Observable just stalls at `toSortedList()`.

The Subscribe:

```
.subscribe(object: Subscriber<GroupedObservable<String, NearbyLocationItem>>() {
    override fun onNext(p0: GroupedObservable<String, NearbyLocationItem>?) {
        val locationItems = ArrayList<NearbyLocationItem>()
        p0.subscribe { loc ->
            locationItems.add(loc)
        }
        locations.put(p0.key, locationItems)
    }


    override fun onCompleted() {
        Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "Never called")
    }

    override fun onError(p0: Throwable?) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add `doOnNext` and `doOnCompleted` at points and see where the events get lost?

Comment: A `OnCompleted` is never triggered and the `OnNext` events stop just before `toSortedList()`

Comment: Maybe you get an exception somewhere but you don't listen to it.

Comment: Wouldn't it show up in the `onError` of the Subscribe? (I have a log there. Just posted a trimmed down version)

Comment: But your `onError` is empty?

Comment: Yep. After the toSortedList the whole thing is dead

Comment: I meant you can add a log in `onError` to check the exception

Comment: There is a log. I posted a trimmed down version. Without the `toSortedList` and the `flatMap` afterwards, I only receive `onNext` Events in the Subscribtion. Yep even without them no `onComplete`.

Comment: @vork `toList` expects the stream to finish, so it can create a list of all emitted elements. If your observable runs indefinitely it will never get past this statement.